# onclick append child component template for every click in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I append a child component on every button click?

The button html:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-add-phone" (click)="addfield()"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> </button>
```

The child component to be loaded on each button click:

```html
<app-farmer-registration-phone *ngIf="loadComponent"></app-farmer-registration-phone>
```

Component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-farmer-registration',
  templateUrl: './farmer-registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./farmer-registration.component.css']
})
export class FarmerRegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
public   loadComponent = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

    addfield(){
        this.loadComponent = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please be specific about the issue you are facing and the result you are looking for.

Comment: Agreed with @JacobNelson!

Comment: Is that `addfield` uses forloop? I am show the all HTML part not just button markup

Comment: Are you getting any error for this or what?

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot In what way you suggesting for duplicate? I mean (to me) it not clear what OP wants

Comment: when I'm doing button click with above code only one time only the child component is added, I want to add it on every click

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I understood what he wants. Its kind a approach he is asking. He is not aware about how to achieve.

Comment: the template contain so much html code that's why i'm not using adding each element(not using Renderer2) in parent component

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot Well but I seems that both que. are fairly irrelevant!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*ngFor` on array, so you need to make a Temp array Like below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-farmer-registration',
  templateUrl: './farmer-registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./farmer-registration.component.css']
})
export class FarmerRegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
public   loadComponent:any[] = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

    addfield(){
        this.loadComponent.push(1);

    }
}
```

**And your html like below:**
The button html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-add-phone" (click)="addfield()"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> </button>
```

The child component to be loaded on each button click:

```
<app-farmer-registration-phone *ngFor="let item of loadComponent"></app-farmer-registration-phone>
```

Comment: it's working, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So for this you have to use `ngFor`

First, make a dummy `array`. And iterate through that `array` to add `child component`.

[**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txwwrp)

> **Component**

```
arr = [];

addfield() {
  this.arr.push(''); // just add an empty string or whatever
}
```

> **Html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arr">
  <app-farmer-registration-phone></app-farmer-registration- 
   phone>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-add-phone" (click)="addfield()"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by a for loop with the child component.

Assume an array, then push new index into it while clicking on add Button.

Follow the code.

**Array**

```
public items = []

public add () {
 this.items = [...this.items, this.items.length]
}
```

**Child Component**

```
<app-farmer-registration-phone *ngFor="let item of items" ></app-farmer-registration-phone>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwjxx9)